# Ubuntu 13.04 Shutdown Abruptly at Midnight

Tags: hardware

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer. Few days back I noticed that my Operating System shuts down abruptly at 12 in midnight. I have searched for it everywhere but I couldn't find any help.

If there is anything I could do to solve this problem of mine, I am all ears.

Thanks.

Comment: 12 at midnight!!. Aaaah Thats a different issue!!!

Comment: What's the output of `sudo atq` ?

Comment: is there any way i could fix it??

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio nothing.

Comment: What about this: `dpkg -l | grep shutdown` and this: `dpkg -l | grep schedule`

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio for dpkg -l | grep schedule the output is 'ii  gnome-schedule 2.1.1-4' nothing for other command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, according to the output of `dpkg -l | grep schedule` you have gnome-schedule installed, which is probably scheduling a shutdown at 12 in midnight everyday. Just try to open gnome-schedule and remove the scheduled activity that shut your system down every day at 12 at midnight (if is there any).
If you want you can attach a screen of gnome-schedule in the question, so I can check if is there any "shutdown activity".

Comment: There is no task assigned..!! It's showing nothing.

Comment: Try running it as root: `sudo gnome-schedule`

Comment: When i ran it using sudo there was a process scheduled to shut down the PC at midnight. I have removed it. And it worked. Thanks Bro!